# Length of module $\otimes A[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $A$-module of finite length, i.e. $\ell_A(M)<+\infty$. I would like to compute the length $$(*) \: \: \: \ell_{A[X]}(M\otimes_AA[X]),$$ where $A[X]$ is the canonical  polynomial ring on $A$. As it has been pointed out in the comments we have to assume that ($*$) is finite. I think that ($*$) is equal to $\ell_A(M)$, but I do not know how to proceed. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried this with $A$ a field, $M=A$?

Comment: Yes. I have to add the assumption $\ell_{A[X]}(M\otimes_AA[X])<+\infty$.

Comment: The only time (*) is finite is when $M=0$, so there is not much to do.